# Get average of averages in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have three models like these

```py
    class School(models.Model):
      # some fields

    class Class(models.Model):
       school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='classes')

    class Student(models.Model):
       class = models.ForeignKey(Class, related_name='students')
       degree = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to order schools using average degree , but the average degree Isn't just the average of all the students as the number of the students in the same class are not equal

so I need to get some thing like this

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch, Avg
classes = Prefetch('classes', Class.objects.all().annotate(avg_degree=Avg('students__degree'))


# this line would through an error
qs = School.objects.all().prefetch_related(classes)
.annotate(avg_degree=Avg('classes__avg_degree')).order_by('avg_degree')
```

of course I can't just use

```
qs = School.objects.all().annotate(avg_degree=Avg('classes__student__degree'))
```

this would give wrong answers

Comment: IMHO the average of the students would be more fair. If there are two classes, one with two students, and one with ten students, then why would the students in the first class have five times more impact than the students in the second class?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree with you, but that is the client's requirements and I can't change this ... also the real problem is not with a school but for simplicity, I used this example

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot annotate on columns that are created using another `annotate`. `Prefetch` does not provide access to `annotate`'d fields, it's primarily used to filter. If you don't need to operate on that queryset further (need only values), you can use raw query solution:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg, F

query = (
    Class.objects
    .annotate(avg_degree=Avg('students__degree'), s_id=F('school'))
    .values('s_id', 'deg')
    .query
)
sql, params = query.sql_with_params()
template = '''
SELECT 
    temp.s_id as id, 
    AVG(temp.deg) as degree 
FROM ({}) "temp" 
GROUP BY temp.s_id
'''
qs = School.objects.raw(template.format(sql), params)

# Now we have required field:
for obj in qs:
    print(obj.id, obj.degree)
```